# A simple definition of n-category

Tags: higher-category-theory

Maybe there is no simple definition of $n$-category understandable for a physicist. Then I would like to know what are the trivial $0$-category,  trivial $1$-category, trivial $2$-category, etc. How to obtain trivial $1$-category from trivial $0$-category? How to obtain trivial $2$-category from trivial $1$-category? etc

== add ==

After that  I would like to know the definition of 0-category that allows us to obtain all the 0-categories, and the  definition of 1-category that allows us to obtain all the 1-categories etc.

I am looking for a particular kind of n-categories.
Based on the answer of André Henriques, it appears that
the trivial 0-category that I am looking for is an one-dimensional vector space. A less trivial 0-category is a n-dimensional vector space, which is a composition of n trivial 0-categories. The trivial 1-category is a category of vector spaces, with only one simple object, which is a trivial object corresponding to an one-dimensional vector space, and the composition of several simple objects gives us a composite object which corresponds to a finite dimensional vector space.

I also guess that the trivial 0-category (ie an one-dimensional vector space) and the composite 0-categories (ie n-dimensional vector spaces) are all the 0-categories (of this type). The category of all vectors spaces is the "trivial" 1-category. All possible 1-categories (of this type) are fusion categories. Along this line, the "trivial" 2-category is the collection of all fusion categories. Then what are the most general 2-categories. 
We need a definition here.

The purpose of this question is not to find out an answer, but to find out a proper way to ask the question. I hope after some exchanges, I know what really is the question that I want to ask.

Comment: What do you mean by "trivial"?

Comment: I have a guess: The trivial $0$-category is an one-dimensional vector space. A less trivial $0$-category is a $n$-dimensional vector space, which is a composition of $n$ trivial $0$-categories. The trivial $1$-category is a category of vector spaces, with only one simple object, which is a trivial object corresponding to an one-dimensional vector space, and the composition of several simple objects gives us a composite object which corresponds to a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: Two comments: 

1) As a (sort of) physicist, I think the construction given in this [nlab](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2Cn%29-category#1CatIntro) page provides an intuitive notion of how to construct an n-category.

2) It sounds like what you're interested in then is a parallel construction which begins with Vect rather than Set, i.e. the n-fold iterated enrichment over Vect. Is this the case?

Comment: That is a strange way to use the word "trivial" (and in particular it doesn't agree with how mathematicians use it; to me the trivial $0$-category is either the zero-element set or the one-element set, for example). Maybe you're asking for a description of deloopings of $\text{Vect}$? You can start here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-vector+space

Comment: Thanks,  Matthew Titsworth and  Qiaochu Yuan. Maybe the n-fold iterated enrichment over Vect is what I want. I will also check the deloopings of Vect.

Comment: @Matthew: I don't think the OP is looking for iterated enrichments. The pattern that begins "a vector space, the category of vector spaces," together with the fact that the OP is a physicist, strongly suggests that the OP is thinking about target catgories for $n$-dimensional (Atiyah-Segal style) field theories, and one physically relevant (I think) choice for these are iterated deloopings of $\text{Vect}$.

Comment: I recommend http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-category

Answer (score 11):

I'll interpret "definition understandable for a physicist" to mean "please give me a bunch of examples to keep in mind". Here you go:

Here are some examples of 0-categories:

- a set with $n$ elements.
- a vector space of dimension $n$ (strictly speaking, that's an example of a 0-category with extra structure, namely a linear structure)

Here are some examples of 1-categories:

- the category of all sets.
- the category of all groups.
- the category of all Lie algebras.
- the category of all vectors spaces (once again, that's an example of a category with extra structure, namely a linear structure)
- the category Mod-$A$ of all modules over a fixed algebra $A$ (once again, this has a linear structure).
- the category of d-dimensional cobordisms between (d-1)-dimensional manifolds.
- the fundamental groupoid of a topological space.

Here are some examples of 2-categories:

- the 2-category of algebras, bimodules, and maps between bimodules.
- the 2-category of cobordisms, where you allow corners of codimension 2.
- the fundamental 2-groupoid of a space (you look at points of the space, paths between points, and homotopies between paths).
- the 2-category of categories, functors, and natural transformations.
- the 2-category of $\mathcal C$-modules, where $\mathcal C$ is a fixed tensor category (again, there are notions of functors, and of natural transformations between those)
- the 2-category of CFTs, their topological defects, and all possible (topological) field insertions.

Here are some examples of n-categories that work for any $n$:

- the n-category of cobordisms, where you allow corners up to codimension $n$.
- the fundamental n-groupoid of a topological space.
- the category of $\mathcal C$-modules, where $\mathcal C=(\mathcal C,\otimes)$ is an $(n-1)$-category equipped with a monoidal product.
- the collection of all $(n-1)$-categories.
- the collections of all QFTs of dimension $n$, along with their (topological) defects of all possible dimensions (i.e. starting from domain walls, and going all the way down to point-like fields).

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful! I am interested in the n-category related to the vector space. Here are my additional guesses: The trivial 0-category (ie an one-dimensional vector space) and composite 0-category (ie $n$-dimensional vector space) are all the 0-categories (of this type). The category of all vectors spaces is the "trivial" 1-category. All possible 1-categories (of this type) are unitary fusion categories. Along this line, the "trivial" 2-category is the collection of all unitary fusion categories. Then what are the most general 2-categories. We need definition

Comment: I would like to have a definition that allows us to obtain all the 2-categories (and 3-categories, etc)  of this type. Maybe "of this type" = the linear structure that you mentioned. It seems that "the collection of all (n−1)-categories" only give us the "trivial" n-category. How to define the the most general non-trivial n-categories (of this type)?

Comment: I see... So really your question is how does one best continue the sequence: [0:finite dimensional Hilbert spaces], [1:unitary fusion categories], [2:????] (or maybe a somewhat easier question would be how to best continue the sequence: [0:finite dimensional vector spaces], [1:fusion categories], [2:????]). One thing to realize is that this sequence is really **doubly indexed**. Vector spaces sit in degree $(0,\infty)$, whereas fusion categories sit in degree $(1,1)$. Braided fusion categories sit in degree $(1,2)$. Have a look at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/periodic+table for more info.

Comment: Finite dimensional vector spaces are the dualizable objects in all vector spaces. In http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.7188.pdf it is shown that fusion categories are dualizable objects in a certain 3 category. I suspect therefore that what you are looking for is a sequence of monoidal n-categories in which the dualizable objects are interesting.