# A definition of a version of n-category with linear structure and tensor product

Tags: higher-category-theory

Let us assume that the $m$-categories with $0\leq m <n$ are
already defined.

1) A $n$-category has a set of $p$-morphisms, labeled by $i^{[p]}$, for
$0\leq p <n$, and each set of the $p$-morphisms admits a direct sum $\oplus$
operations: $i^{[p]}\oplus j^{[p]}=k^{[p]}$.  The  $0$-morphisms also admit a tensor product $\otimes$
operation: $i^{[0]}\otimes j^{[0]}=k^{[0]}$.

2) The set of $p$-morphisms (for a fixed $p$) admits an action by the 
$(n-p-1)$-categories via another tensor product $\boxtimes$, which
is compactible with the $\oplus$ operation between the $p$-morphisms.

3) A generic excitation is described by a $n$-dimensional cell-complex $C$ ($C$
is a tranglation of the space).  Each $p$-cell ($0\leq p <n$) carries an index
$i^{[p]}$ that labels a $p$-morphism and the $n$-cells  carry no label. For each
generic excitation there is a fusion spaces $V(C)$ (which is vector space for the linear structure).

4) ... ... (Addition conditions)

I wonder if there is a (well defined) definition in Math which is closely related to the above incomplete definition?

This is related to a previous question
[A simple definition of n-category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157103/a-simple-definition-of-n-category)

Comment: Condition 2) requires that the p-morphism is a module category. 3) is the linear structure. They come from TQFT. What I try to define here is not just a higher category.